# Can a structure implement multiple signatures in Standard ML?

Tags: types, sml

I've recently got wondering whether Standard ML structures can implement multiple signatures, similar to how a class can implement multiple interfaces in Java. A quick search revealed [this web page](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/modules/sigstruct.htm) where Bob Harper says that this would, indeed, be possible (emphasis mine):

> [...] the relationship between signatures and structures in ML is
>   **many-to-many**, whereas in some languages (such as Modula-2) the
>   relationship is one-to-one or many-to-one.  This means that in ML a
>   signature may serve as the interface for many different structures,
>   and that **a structure may implement many different signatures**.

However, I can't find the syntax and a cursory look over the grammar of modules in the revised definition doesn't seem to support the above quote.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible?
2. If yes, what's the syntax?

EDIT: After some playing around, I think that Bob Harper was actually referring to **signature matching**. This snippet is a small example where a structure is found as a match for two different signatures:

```
signature S1 = sig val s1 : int end
signature S2 = sig val s2 : string end

functor F1 (A : S1) = struct val f1 = A.s1 end
functor F2 (B : S2) = struct val f2 = B.s2 end

structure C =
struct
  val s1 = 1
  val s2 = "1"
end

structure F1C = F1 (C)
structure F2C = F2 (C)
```

At this point, I presume that, yes, a structure can be seen as implementing multiple signatures, but there's no way to enforce that using a signature specification in the structure declaration, such as:

```
structure C : S1 and S2 = ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no syntax to enforce it with a *single* annotation, but you could e.g. do

```
structure C = struct ... end
structure C1 : S1 = C
structure C2 : S2 = C
```

If you merely want to have the sanity checks but avoid polluting the scope with auxiliary structure names, you could make them local:

```
structure C = struct ... end
local
  structure C1 : S1 = C
  structure C2 : S2 = C
in end
```

Unfortunately, one cannot use wildcards in structure bindings...

The notation you suggested would be tricky, since it effectively would introduce an intersection operator on signatures. That has far-reaching consequences. Consider, for example:

```
signature S1 = sig type 'a t; val v : int t; val w : string t end
signature S2 = sig val v : int end
functor F (X : S1 and S2) = (* what is X.t here? *)
```

There are two possible solutions for what type `X.t` could be so that the type of `X.v` is consistent with both signatures: either

```
type 'a t = int
```

or

```
type 'a t = 'a
```

The problem is that they are incomparable, i.e., none is better than the other. In one case `X.w` would be an int, in the other a string. Essentially, what is happening here is that you'd introduce a form of higher-order unification through the backdoor, which is known to be undecidable in the general case.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the only place where a structure's type actually matters, a functor's param, we can't use the same structure as two different signatures. Unless, we apply your trick `F (structure C1 = C; structure C2 = C)`.

I've also realized that there would be a way of combining two signatures, using `include`: `signature S12 = sig include S1 include S2 end`. But, yeah, it fails to compile with the example you gave for intersection types.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, that is not quite correct. You can of course manually write out the combined signature you desire (if it exists), and it will be a subtype of both S1 and S2 (because signatures are structural types). You just cannot express it as intersection. Also, I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Why would you want to write a functor like that?

Comment: It was a question out of pure curiosity, I'm not actually trying to do something with this. Also, regarding `include`. I realize I can manually merge two signatures, but using `include` would have been a way to "combine" two signatures without actually declaring one. Like in: `structure C : sig include S1 include S2 end = ...`. That looks like a more verbose notation for `structure C : S1 and S2 = ...`, but it doesn't have the semantics of intersection types.